# Firestore OrderBy on Multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order by my Firestore query based on a timestamp named "issueTime" with pagination. Since I'm using a where condition with ">=" and "<=" on a field named as "tag_name", I'm forced to order by based on "tag_name" before the "issueTime" field. So, now the data first orders by tag_name and then orders by issueTime. But I'm trying to order it based on issueTime.
Is there any work around for this ?

```
    let keyQuery = query(docRef,
    where("buildingID", "==", buildingId),
    where('tag_name', ">=", searchValue), 
    where('tag_name', "<=", searchValue + "\uf8ff"),
    orderBy('tag_name', 'asc'), 
    orderBy('issueTime', 'asc'), 
    limit(PAGE_LIMIT));
```

Comment: This query seems to need composite index to be made as whenever there is a need for multiple orderBy we need to create composite index, But if you can assign that timestamp to a separate field in every document which consist of day month and year then you can use it with where field. Take look at this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview)

Comment: Does that solved your issue ?